# Show divider on ionic-selectable

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I use `eakoriakin/ionic-selectable` on my `ionic 4` project.

I got a list team matching this model :

```
export class Team {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
}
```

I use the selectable elements like this :

```
<ionic-selectable
      closeButtonText="Fermez"
      closeButtonSlot="end"
      [items]="allTeams"
      itemValueField="id"
      itemTextField="name"
      [canSearch]="true"
      (onChange)="teamChanged($event)">
</ionic-selectable>
```

It is possible to add some `divider` to separate some `team` and How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a grouping items feature explained in the [wiki](https://github.com/eakoriakin/ionic-selectable/wiki#grouping-items).

You need to add a grouping property to your data like `teamGroup`:

```
export class Team {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    teamGroupId: number;
    teamGroupName: string;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<ionic-selectable
      closeButtonText="Fermez"
      closeButtonSlot="end"
      [items]="allTeams"
      itemValueField="id"
      itemTextField="name"
      [canSearch]="true"
      groupValueField="teamGroupId"
      groupTextField="teamGroupName"
      (onChange)="teamChanged($event)">
        <ng-template ionicSelectableGroupTemplate let-group="group">
          {{group.text}}
        </ng-template>
</ionic-selectable>
```

You can see some more information about this on the individual attribute docs:

- [groupColor](https://github.com/eakoriakin/ionic-selectable/wiki#groupcolor)
- [groupValueField](https://github.com/eakoriakin/ionic-selectable/wiki#groupvaluefield)
- [groupTextField](https://github.com/eakoriakin/ionic-selectable/wiki#grouptextfield)